# Can an Australian enter the USA once a month, from Mexico, under the Visa Waiver Program?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

The jist of the matter is that I have potential work in Los Angeles. I am an Australian citizen living in Australia. I had the idea of moving to Tijuana and basing myself there, entering the US (California) maybe once a month to confer with the people I work for, for 1-3 days.

The way I look at it, I will be an Australian citizen, freelancing while holidaying in Mexico. On top of that I would be entering the US for short periods to consult with business associates (listed as an approved action under the [visa waiver's business section](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html))

The thing I am worried about is that [this stack exchange thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-usa-having-stayed-for-90-days-under-the-visa-waiver) mentions that time spent in Mexico or Canada counts towards the 90 days total allowed in the US under all these rules. Would this be the case for me even if I am only spending maybe 5-10 days in the US during this 90 day period? It hardly seems like I am 'trying to live in the US and circumvent the 90 day limit' if I am barely even in the US.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I should clarify that I would like to do this consistently for a period of time that might be anywhere from 6 months to a few years.

Comment: Have you investigated what you would need to live and work in Mexico?

Comment: I think the situation you are asking about will be one of those "at the CBP officer's discretion" items. But keep in mind that regular visits from Mexico to the USA could also be viewed as suspicious for other reasons.

Comment: Are you proposing to live _illegally_ in Mexico?! Then you could run into a problem.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes. It is completely okay to stay in Mexico as an Australian and receive income from an outside source. You are _not_ allowed to receive income from a Mexican source though (which I would not be). You can stay for 6 months without a visa, and every source I can find says renewing the 6 month period is as simple as a trip to any border, without even having to cross sometimes.

Comment: @Tom That is the impression that I am getting. If I am upfront about conferring with a client I am hoping they will okay with it. I also have a close friend living in San Diego as a back up reason to enter the country and for help if I get into a sticky situation

Comment: @MichaelHampton No. My setup in Mexico will be completely legal. From what I have read renting property is not a problem during a visa free visit in Mexico, which is available to Australian citizens. I won't have a car either, which will also make things easier.

Comment: @D.Wells: There is an unwritten rule on how long you need to be outside Mexico to get a new visa-on-arrival/passport stamp. Some people might get it without having to cross sometimes at some crossings. The only time I tried this I was denied and the officer was not impressed. Also you don't necessarily get 6 months. There are some rules at each border or crossing and part is up to the officer. But yeah there's more and more details which are further and further off topic for our site so the expat site would be much better for getting all the info sorted.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your input, I might pose the same question to the Expat site, thanks for the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VWP status for stays longer than 90 days in Mexico](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51359/vwp-status-for-stays-longer-than-90-days-in-mexico)

Comment: TJ is a bit strange in that you can cross over without interacting with Mexican customs officials. The long queues and hassles with US customs are legendary, and having trips across that border crossing on your record will likely result in questions for years afterwards, if you need to go to the US.

Answer (score 1):

Residents of Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean are treated differently with respect to the rules designed to circumvent visa runs to Canada, Mexico, or the Caribbean.

> If you are admitted to the United States under the VWP, you may take a short trip to Canada, Mexico, or a nearby island and generally be readmitted to the United States under the VWP for the remainder of the original 90 days granted upon your initial arrival in the United States. Therefore, the length of time of your total stay, including the short trip, must be 90 days or less. See the CBP website. Citizens of VWP countries who reside in Mexico, Canada, or a nearby island are generally exempted from the requirement to show onward travel to another country when entering the United States. Learn more on the CBP website.

Source: https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html

Most importantly, the rules concern travelers who take "short trips" to Canada, Mexico, or adjacent islands; you will not be such a traveler.

Comment: @pnuts exactly.

Comment: But would the OP be a "resident" of Mexico, since they are only "holidaying" there?

Comment: @Tom the traveler is staying legally in Mexico for 6 months or more.  I believe that counts as residence.

Comment: @pnuts no, I think I misread your question.  The rule that doesn't apply is the "time in Mexico counts the same as time in the US" rule.

Comment: @pnuts yes, an Australian can enter once a month from Mexico.  This assumes that each entry is for a few days, as proposed in the question.  Obviously if the border officer thinks the traveler is living in the US (which violates the terms of the VWP), the traveler will be denied entry.

Comment: @phoog - Can you document your statement about 6 month stay as tourist equals "resident"?  Ultimately, as in my first comment on the OP, it will be up to the CBP officer.

Comment: @Tom Yes, it's up to the CBP officer.  But look at it this way: even someone who's *not* claiming residence in Mexico could come to the US once a month for a week on the VWP, spending all of their other time in Mexico, whether over a period of 6 months or even just 4 months.  There's nothing in the rules that prohibits that, is there?